# ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument'))

Tags: python, requests

Есть набор ссылок с сайта [росказны](https://roskazna.gov.ru/), вот часть из них:

```
links = [
    'https://roskazna.gov.ru/upload/iblock/b90/30.11.2023repo_21.XML',
    'https://roskazna.gov.ru/upload/iblock/158/29.11.2023repo.XML',
    'https://roskazna.gov.ru/upload/iblock/19a/29.11.2023repo_27.XML',
    'https://roskazna.gov.ru/upload/iblock/2d0/28.11.2023repo.XML',
    'https://roskazna.gov.ru/upload/iblock/3d9/28.11.2023repo_7.XML'
]
```

Необходимо собрать информацию с каждого xml файла. Для этого делаю обычный get запрос, и сначала некоторые ссылки успешно обрабатываются, но затем вылетает ошибка

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(22, 'Invalid argument'))
```

Часть кода:

```
headers = {
   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 
   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link, headers = headers, timeout=0.5, verify=False)
    doc = doc.split('/')[4]
    with open(doc, "wb") as code:
        code.write(r.content)
```

Не понимаю, в чем вообще проблема и как ее исправить. Версия браузера хром в user-agent указана правильно. Работаю в jupyter notebook на macbook air m1

Comment: Ну так печатайте линк по которому обращаетесь. Может там какие-то линки проблемные. На котором упадёт смотрите, чем он отличается от других. Кстати, вы файл каждую итерацию цикла перезаписываете.